# make a shell script to be run as a second user

Tags: shell-script

I am making a script where I wish to run two services as a certain user. The script should switch to a user and then run a program and after the program has been executed, it should start running the second program.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u username -s -- "program1 && program2"
```

or

```
sudo -u username bash -c 'program1 && program2'
```

Comment: This is how I was planning to run. su -s /bin/bash user -c /optimal.sh I want to use the sleep command for 2 minutes and then run the another script. how am I going to achieve this.

It takes two minutes to finish the executing the first program and after the first program is done running. I want it to start running the second program only after the first program is finished running. How I am going to achieve this. I will be using the sleep command but how should i write it

Comment: No need to use sleep to achieve what you want. You can either start the first program and if finished and executed properly , then start the second program: 
"program1 && program2"
or start the first program and when finished, execute the second program independently if the first one executed properly or not: "program1; program2"

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command can be told to run as a specific user:

```
 -u user, --user=user
             Run the command as a user other than the default target user
             (usually root).  The user may be either a user name or a
             numeric user ID (UID) prefixed with the ‘#’ character (e.g.
             #0 for UID 0).
```

So, inside your script, you can use `sudo -u USERNAME` to run the two services:

```
sudo -u foo command1
sudo -u foo command2
```

However, this means that the script itself will need to be run as root. Otherwise, the `sudo` will ask for the password of the user `foo`.

Comment: This is how I was planning to run. su -s /bin/bash user -c /optimal.sh I want to use the sleep command for 2 minutes and then run the another script. how am I going to achieve this. It takes two minutes to finish the executing the first program and after the first program is done running. I want it to start running the second program only after the first program is finished running. How I am going to achieve this. I will be using the sleep command but how should i write it

Comment: @Mintu 1) please don't do this. You need to have everything in your question instead of adding each requirement with a comment. 2) I have shown you how to do this. Use `sudo -u username command`. The second command will only be run after the first one has finished. There is no need for `sleep`.

Comment: re: last paragraph: `sudo` would ask for the password of the user running the `sudo` command, not the runas user.  Also `/etc/sudoers` can be configured so that user `foo` can run commands as non-root users without a passwd, just as it can allow foo to run commands as root without a passwd, e.g:  `foo ALL=(otheruser) NOPASSWD : /path/to/command1 /path/to/command2`